# How do i edit my table with a specific condition using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a pivot table developed from the next data image. My problem is that in the case of week 36 and 37 I didn't spend on personal care but i still want the projected spending for the weeks to be reflective in the pivot table.
[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTDMm.png)

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6npVv.png)

```
Public Sub Revamp()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim count As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim trig As Boolean


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'For loop that checks column WeekNum for the current week
For i = 1 To 52
    count = 0
    trig = False
    
'Groceries Loop
    Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 3).Value <> vbNullString
        
        If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i And _
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 7).Value = "Groceries" And _
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 2).Value = "2019" And _
            trig = False Then


            ws.Cells(9 + count, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 10) = 12
            'ensures that the first occurrence of the If condition carries the Projected price for 
            'the week 
            trig = True
        End If
        
   
        
    count = count + 1
    Loop

'Personal Care
    count = 0
    trig = False
    
    Do While ws.Cells(9 + count, 3).Value <> vbNullString
        If ws.Cells(9 + count, 5).Value = i And _
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 7).Value = "Personal_Care" And _
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 2).Value = "2019" And _
            trig = False Then


            ws.Cells(9 + count, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            ws.Cells(9 + count, 10) = 17
            trig = True
         End If
    count = count + 1
    Loop

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: simplest way is to add a line item for personal care for the weeks and enter $0 and $17 projected spending.

Comment: This wont work because i have more than 500entries. I want to automate the process.